# How can I convert Excel Files to Google Sheets with Files more than 20 MB?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps, drive

In another script, I was able to convert a Excel File in Google Drive to Google Sheets format. I used the Drive API (`Drive.Files.insert`), it was OK with files smaller than 5 MB.

I had a look into Developers Google documentation and I saw that for files larger than 5 MB we have to use a resumable uploadType but I don´t know how to adapt my code to do that.

Could anyone help me?

```
function convertExcelToSheets(destinationFolder,excelENDECAFile) {

  var excelENDECAFileFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Excel ENDECA File (File responses)").next();
  var excelENDECAFile = excelENDECAFileFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL).next();

  Drive.Files.insert (
    {title: 'GS-'+excelENDECAFile.getName(), parents: [{"id": 
    excelENDECAFileFolder.getId()}]},
     excelENDECAFile.getBlob(),
     {convert: true},
  );

}
```

The error I get when I try to run the code for a file with 20 MB is:

> Exception: Unreachable Service: drive v2

Then I´ve tried to use **Drive.Files.copy**

```
    function convertExcelToSheets(excelENDECAFile, fileDate) {


      Drive.Files.copy(
        {title: 'GS-'+excelENDECAFile.getName()},excelENDECAFile.getId(), 
 {convert: true}
      );
    }
```

Sometimes it works but, when the file is big I get an **Empty Response Error**

Here is a dummy file in the same template I have.

[Dummy File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P7kOcVWxB3zJ3--dGctsz2tJ5kJsiUla)

Could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: format your question well...

Comment: Can you provide the information about the Excel file? How much numbers of rows and columns are the Excel file? The official document says `Up to 5 million cells for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.`. [Ref](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en) I'm worry about this limitation. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your return! My Excel File has about 30,000 rows and 67 columns. Yesterday, I tried to use `Drive.Files.copy` and it worked in my home. But now at the Office I´ve tried again with the same file and I got a **Empty response error**. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, when you add more information about your question, please add it to your question by [editing question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57981887/edit). Please don't post it as an answer. So can you remove the answer and add it to your question? About your new issue, can you provide a sample Excel file and script for replicating it? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, we can confirm it and think of the solution.

Comment: @Tanaike done! In the answer you can find the link with a dummy file. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. When I tested your script using your shared file several times, no error occurs. And I could confirm that the file can be converted to Google Spreadsheet. So unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. In your environment, when you run the script with the shared file, does the error of `when the file is big I get an Empty Response Error` occurs?